# How to change the segue transition style from bottom to top instead of right to left in navigation controllers?

Tags: swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, segue, transition

I am trying to change the transition animation in navigation controller to load a new UIView controller from bottom to top, using Segue. I believe it will not be too hard to implement but may be I am not able to understand it.

My first attempt was to use Hero library but it does not work for some reason.

The answers found so far were only in Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution to present your new controller modally.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard Name", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Controller Name
")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```